# Why isn't my custom 404 Error page working?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

The custom 404 Error page I built for my portfolio isn't working. Strangely enough, no 404 page at all is shown. It simply redirects to the home page and keeps the non-existing URL in the address bar.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Redirect 301 /portfolio.php http://timrohweder.com/portfolio/
Redirect 301 /testimonials.php http://timrohweder.com/testimonials/
Redirect 301 /about.php http://timrohweder.com/about/
Redirect 301 /contact.php http://timrohweder.com/contact/
Redirect 301 /bandg.php http://timrohweder.com/portfolio/b-and-g-plumbing/
Redirect 301 /threed.php http://timrohweder.com/portfolio/three-d-landscape-and-concrete-construction/
Redirect 301 /feetforfreedom.php http://timrohweder.com/portfolio/feet-for-freedom/
Redirect 301 /ipsum.php http://timrohweder.com/portfolio/intro-to-ipsum/
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please use more tags (PHP?), tell us about your server, ... (re)read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is that all that's in your htaccess file? Are there other htaccess files? What URL are you going to that you expect a 404 for?

Comment: That's all that is in the .htaccess file. It's just a small portfolio site. I'll just add gibberish to the URL to try and get a 404. Like http://timrohweder.com/jlkfsdajlkfasd

Thanks for the suggestion, Hille. I'll add a PHP tag and read that link. The server is just a shared server through Bluehost. Not sure of its setup... I can log into the cPanel and check something if needed. I'm not very knowledgeable about servers yet.